# Hudson build fails when a user logs out of RDP session

Tags: build, hudson

We are using Hudson to build mixed C++/Java projects with an Ant script.  It is running in Tomcat 6, on a Win XP virtual machine.

I have noticed recently that when a user logs off the machine (from a remote desktop session), builds that are currently running tend to suddenly fail without an error message.

Has anyone encountered anything similar or have an idea what might be causing this effect?  I can post additional information about our setup if needed, I'm just not sure what's relevant in this case.

EDIT: I have tried running the Tomcat service under various users, but this doesn't seem to help.  Tried the standard Local System account, as well as the server Administrator and a domain administrator account.

Comment: Is the user logging out of the virtual machine, or out of the physical machine hosting the virtual machine?

Comment: The user is logging out of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -Xrs to the Tomcat JVM arguments.

For more information see this [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=538ad43947d31bc0b277e8b6766?bug_id=6660258).

Comment: The referenced bug does not seem related to my question.

Hudson is running in Tomcat, as a service.  It does not shut down when a user logs off the machine (nor would we want it to). The pages it serves up are always accessible. However, builds that are running when a person logs off will magically die with no explanation.

I tried adding this to the arguments, just in case, but the same thing still occurs.